# Python dev_appserver cant import `.so` file (Pillow)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

Inside my GAE application I try this:

```
from PIL import Image
```

And get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/code/waxed_backend/src/waxed_backend/concerns/misc/views.py", line 57, in home
    from PIL import Image
  File "libs/PIL/Image.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
  File "/home/sheena/Workspace/Waxed/venvs/wxt_comp/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 1024, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named PIL._imaging
```

`/path/to/libs/PIL/imaging.so` exists. And I have no problem importing anything else from that libs file from within dev_appserver.

And this works fine:

```
cd /path/to/libs/
python
>>> from PIL import Image
```

I can only conclude that either dev_appserver somehow breaks impotrt functionality so that .so files aren't recognised.

Has anyone else seen this before? Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

_imaging is a PIL dependency written in C. Because it's C and not Python, including the library in your lib folder won't work. You need to define that library in your app.yaml file:

```
libraries:
   - name: PIL
     version: latest
```